# Disable soft keyboard for an Edittext

Tags: android

I have an EditText where I want to handle the inputs myself, so I don't want the soft keyboard to show up when I click it (or when selection changes, focus changed, long clicked, etc). However, I still want to be able select the text, change cursor position, copy/past, etc.

I have tried putting android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" in the manifest, but that doesn't seems to do much. I also tried adding the following

```
edittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        EditText edittext = (EditText) v;
        int inType = edittext.getInputType();       // Backup the input type
        edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // Disable standard keyboard
        edittext.onTouchEvent(event);               // Call native handler
        edittext.setInputType(inType);              // Restore input type
        return true; // Consume touch event
    }
});
```

which disables the keyboard, but also prevent the cursor from working.

Currently I'm basically trying to add listeners for all the situations where the keyboard might pop up to toggle it off, but this is very clunky and I can't catch all the cases. Is there a better way to disable the soft keyboard for a particular EditText or fragment?

Comment: If you are handling the inputs yourself why not just a `TextView`? You can make it selectable which I think will give you want you want.

Comment: make editText unselected on touch

Comment: I also want the blinking cursor from the EditText, and would like it to work with hardware keyboard and other input methods.

Comment: Dang, still no answer, I also need this...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the best solution would be if Google gave an inputType that works like this.

The following tends to work. It will sometimes flicker as the keyboard is loaded and then is instantly murdered. But, it just listens for when you click on the textview and then when that happens it murders the keyboard.

It can't account for things like if the textfield gets focus some other way, but for my purposes (I have a textfield for a barcode reader that gets a barcode read into it by a barcode reader (hardware keyboard)), so a softkeyboard makes no sense.

```
editView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (imm != null) {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
                }
            }
        });
```

I also added the other line you might want in there and commented it out. Namely if you want to hide the Android launched soft keyboard or if a user loads the keyboard by holding menu if that might close too.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Disable IME for this application
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
```